# jquery validation message to display on the last td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery

```
rules:{
    gender: {
        required: true
    },
},
messages:{
    gender: {
        required: "Please specify your gender"
    },
},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
        error.insertBefore(element.siblings('input[type="radio"][name="' + element.attr('name') + '"]:last'));
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); font-weight:300">Gender*</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="gender" value="male"/>Male
            <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I get the error message in between the radio buttons spoiling my whole layout! I need it to be prnted in a third td
Ex: `Gender .Male .Female "This field is required"`

Comment: Post the entire code please!

Answer (score 0):

```
rules:{
   gender: {
       required: true
   },
},

messages:{
    gender: {
        required: "Please specify your gender"
    },
},
errorElement: 'span',
highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $('span.error').show();
}
<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); font-weight:300">Gender*</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="gender" value="male"/>Male
            <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="gender" value="female"/>Female
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="display:none"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can use this span element and can also add class to hightlight the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an additional column to show error messages.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var html = "<td>" + error + "</td>";
    html.appendTo(element.parent());
}
```